# how can i display a div repeatedly on a button click

Tags: c#, jquery

The div contain html controls like dropdown , textboxes etc.Dropdown data is binding using c# code .  when a dropdown repeats the binded data must be repeat . how can i implement it using jquery ?

Comment: can you post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add repeated div using bellow code: [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLja9cr8/1/)

```
<input type="button" value="Add More(+)" id="btnAddMore" /> <br/>
<div id="divMain"></div>
<div id="divToCopy" style="display:none;">
  <div>    
    <label>Text: </label>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <label>Dropdown: </label>
    <select>
      <option>value1</option>
      <option>value2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$("#btnAddMore").click(function(){
    var divCopy=$("#divToCopy").html();
  $("#divMain").append(divCopy);
});
```